# rails plugin uses different views path in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a plugin (in my_rails_app/vendor/plugins directory) and its controllers use view from my application (my_rails_app/app/views). When I run it in development mode everything works well, but in staging/production it seems like the plugin looks for partial views in its own directory (my_rails_app/vendor/plugins/my_plugin/app/views).

For example I have controller (in the plugin):

```
module MyPlugin
  class SampleController < ApplicationController
    layout "application"

    def new
      #code
    end
  end
end
```

The layout is OK in both development and production, but the layout's in the template itself, I render a partial:

```
= render :partial => "_head"
```

in development: works well
in production: 
ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial /sample/head, stamper/application/head with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :haml]}. Searched in: 
  * "/my_rails_app/app/views" 
  * "/my_rails_app/vendor/plugins/my_plugin/app/views"

Why production plugin looks for a different path?

Comment: What is the path of `head` partial? Is it `my_rails_app/app/views/sample/`?

Comment: no. my_rails_app/app/views/application/ @MarekLipka

Comment: paste your `development.rb` and `production.rb` contents.